# Matrix derivatives for ML

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, maximum-likelihood

Assume that our data is distributed according to a $\underline d$ dimensional [multivariate Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Likelihood_function) with $\bar \mu$ mean and $\Sigma$ covariance matrix: $$(\mathbf x_1, \dots, \mathbf x_n) \sim \mathcal N(\bar \mu, \Sigma).$$

Using [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) Equation [57, 59], derive $\frac{\partial \mathcal L(\theta)}{\partial \Sigma}$ in matrix form and set it to zero to find $\Sigma_{ML}$ . Assume each $x_i$ is drawn independently.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? What have you tried?

Comment: Once the link to the PDF is broken, how will anyone understand what question you are asking?  Please make your question as self-contained as possible.